# Failed reopen vote audit: moved questions should be closed, right?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

The reopen vote auditor thinks this question is fine: [Generalizing Haskell: could we replace Hask with Cat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705418/generalizing-haskell-could-we-replace-hask-with-cat) I think it should be closed, since the poster "moved" (actually copied) it to cstheory. Who's right?

Assuming I am, I voted to close after seeing the question in the audit. Is that the best thing to do a) in general b) to clue in the auditor for the next time around?

Comment: No, the user didn't *move* it. They posted a second copy elsewhere. The audit choosing system doesn't know anything about that dupe on another site.